# Iphone: ScrollView force to bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, scrollview

I would like a ScrollView to start all the way at the bottom. Any methods?

I have already tried this, but I can't back to top....

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, [yourScrollView contentSize].height);

[yourScrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use the

```
[self.catScroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(fr.frame.origin.x,0 , self.catScroll.frame.size.width, self.catScroll.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
```

where `catScroll` is scrollView

or To use the `setContentOffset:` change this property in `scrollView`'s delegate method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` to new contentoffset

I think this will definitely helps you.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Here i have used horizontal scroll so i have set it's x of frame origin see the first line of answer just put the frame you want to visible in your case just put CGRectMake(0,Content_Size in height-Scroll View's height,width,height) put it to scrollRectToVisible:

Answer (score 1):

you should call

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, [yourScrollView contentSize].height); 
[yourScrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];
```

in viewDidLoad. And check `yourScrollView` it should be correctly connected to it's IBOutlet, or received from `[self.view viewWithTag:];` and `contentSize` should be set to `UIScrollView` contents size before you'll try to change `contentOffset`.

BTW to make it at the bottom from start you should set animated:NO